# Python cannot import name serial

Tags: python, serialization, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to communicate with my Arduino over serial using Python. I've installed pyserial, and this is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from serial import serial
print("helloworld")
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)

a=raw_input("enter value")
ser.write(a)
```

When I try to run the code this is What I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vm/Desktop/serial.py", line 2, in <module>
    from serial import serial
  File "/home/vm/Desktop/serial.py", line 2, in <module>
    from serial import serial
ImportError: cannot import name serial
```

Answer (score 5):

You've named your script `serial`. It's trying to import `serial` from itself. Rename your script.

Comment: So what would I have to change, sorry in a bit new to python.

Comment: The name of your script.

Comment: so i can't name it serial.py

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
```

when doing

```
from a import b
```

you are trying to import member b from module a.

when doing

```
import a
```

you are importing the whole module a.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Hi You Have Too USE bellow code

> `from serial import Serial`

Comment: When your answer is too short, you can send as a comment.